# How to align text while printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to print an HTML table which i am successfully doing, but issue I am facing is that I want to align two column's data to right while printing but that not happening

I am using `CSS` `@media print` to achieve this but not getting the result

I have 2 columns `TO Qty` and `AcceptedQty` to both of them I have given a class which I am giving some style while printing.

This is the CSS I am using:

```
.show-on-print {
    display: none;
}

@media print {
  .show-on-print {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .test {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

js to print table

```
function printData() {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById("printFull");
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
}

$('#print').on('click', function() {
  printData();
})
```

Here is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/87pdhtaz/2/) i have commented the line where i am giving class name i have commented that

Please check what I am doing wrong

Comment: Please, add your code to the question, not just as a jsFiddle.

Comment: where you what that 2 columns i am little bit confused

Comment: @Tom that two columns are `TOQty` and `AcceptedQty` i am printing full table but when i am printing i want data of these two columns to be right align and others are already left-aligned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `$(tabCell).css('text-align', 'right');` after `tabCell.classList.add("test");`

Answer (score 3):

It's happening because you're outputting the html into a new document that doesn't copy the CSS over to that document.

You need to add inline CSS or append it to the html like this:

```
  var style = "<style> .text-right{text-align:right}</style>";
  newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML + style);
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yx5d43cr/).